# how to reference controller function from another controller

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

Trying to learn ASP MVC coming from Linux/LAMP background (in other words I'm a newb) ...

For some reason I can't seem to use a function defined in a controller in another controller.

Here's the function in my MessagesController.cs file:

```
    public List<Message> GetMessagesById(string username)
    {
        return db.Messages.Where(p => p.user == username).ToList();
    }
```

When I try to reference it:

```
    using LemonadeTrader.Models;
    using LemonadeTrader.Controllers;     // added this to pull the Messages::getMesssagesById
    ...

    ViewBag.messages = lemondb.Messages.GetMessagesById(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
```

I get something along the lines of lemondb.Messages does not contain a method called GetMesssagesById.

How do I reference it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `GetMessageById` (and all other methods needed for accessing messages) to separate class and use the class everywhere you need to get `Message` data.

```
MessageService service = new MessageService();
ViewBag.messages = service.GetMessagesById(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would your proposed MessageService class be a model or a controller class. Or does it matter?

Comment: It is model class / business logic.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be linking controller methods like this, not to mention that controllers shouldn't be performing data access directly. I would recommend you externalizing this function into a separate class/repository which could be used by both controllers.

Example:

```
public class MessagesRepository
{
    public List<Message> GetMessagesById(string username)
    {
        return db.Messages.Where(p => p.user == username).ToList();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class FooController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new MessagesRepository()
        ViewBag.messages = db.GetMessagesById(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
        return View();
    }
}

public class BarController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new MessagesRepository()
        ViewBag.messages = db.GetMessagesById(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
        return View();
    }
}
```

OK, that's the first step. This code could be improved by decoupling the controllers from the repository by introducing an abstraction for this repository:

```
public interface IMessagesRepository
{
    List<Message> GetMessagesById(string username);
}

public class MessagesRepository: IMessagesRepository
{
    public List<Message> GetMessagesById(string username)
    {
        return db.Messages.Where(p => p.user == username).ToList();
    }
}
```

then you could use constructor injection for those controllers:

```
public class FooController: Controller
{
    private readonly IMessagesRepository _repository;
    public class FooController(IMessagesRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.messages = _repository.GetMessagesById(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
        return View();
    }
}

public class BarController: Controller
{
    private readonly IMessagesRepository _repository;
    public class BarController(IMessagesRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.messages = _repository.GetMessagesById(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
        return View();
    }
}
```

finally you would configure your DI framework to pass the corresponding implementation into those controllers.

I would also recommend you replacing this `ViewBag` with a strongly typed view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Messages = _repository.GetMessagesById(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString())
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is your abstract MessagesRepository different from just moving this method to a model class?You got to another question I had (but didn't ask it) about whether it was better to pass the model or use the viewbag.

Comment: @micahhoover, the view model is a a class which contains information that the view needs. Quite often it represents a POCO class containing properties to be shown in the view. So the usual workflow is the following: a controller action uses a repository to fetch some model, it fills a view model from the information returned by the repository and passes the view model to the view. As far as the `ViewBag` is concerned, personally I always recommend against its usage. Strongly typed views and view models are the correct way to architect an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Thanks for elaboring, Darin. I'm trying to appreciate your suggestion even though I am a novice. Why would it be better to have a Model, a View, and a separate Model View? As I get a little more experience I will weigh your words on type safety, but right now, I'm just trying to get something working.

Comment: @micahhoover, normally the M in MVC stands for View Model. This is a class that you pass to the view. This class is specifically designed for the given view. Your data access layer is something completely separate from the web application. It could be reused in other applications. It works with Models. Those models are classes that reflect your business requirements. The view models are just a specific representation of those business models for a particular screen in a particular ASP.NET MVC application.